# Sort wp_query posts with given array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, sorting

I have this

```
$products = new \WP_Query([
     'post_type' => 'product',
     'posts_per_page' => 12,
     'paged' => $paged,
     'post__in' => [121, 15, 125]
]);
```

Now I want to sort products according to this array

```
$best_selling_products = [15, 125, 121];
```

I've tried adding 'order_by' => 'post__in' but it doesn't work for this stuff :/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this function, you can sort by slug ID or what ever you want..

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
        if ($a->slug == $b->slug) {
            return 0;
        }
        return ($a->slug < $b->slug) ? -1 : 1;
    }
    
    usort($products,"cmp");

   var_dump($products);
```